# Read from TCP / UDP PHP without privileges

Tags: php, sockets, web, tcp, udp

I Have a device that sends data via UDP or TCP.

I need to read This data from my server, the problem is that i Have a server in a shared hosting and i don’t have the privileges to enable ports reading.

Is there a way to read this data anyway? I just need to call an url from This device but unfortunately it doesnt have HTTP protocol for data transfer, only TCP / UDP

Comment: If you can't open the port then your server can't receive the data. You'll need to have the device send the data to a machine you've got more control over. Then that machine would have to foward the data to your shared server using HTTP (assuming you still need that shared server, and don't just decide to move your entire site to a more flexible hosting environment). But first, I suggest explaining to the hosting company what you are trying to do, and ask nicely if they would open the ports for you, and allow you to run a server-side daemon which monitors them.

Comment: @ADyson no other way?

Comment: No. A port is a port, if you can't open it, and you can't change the route of the traffic, then that's the end of the story